# Cordova 2.7 - iOS Plugin SQLite exec deprecated

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, deprecated

Hello Phonegap Experts,

We have updated our iOS app to Cordova 2.7. Now we get an error message when using the "PhoneGap iOS SQLitePlugin (brodyspark / latest version)".

The old format of this exec call has been removed (deprecated since 2.1). Change to:

```
cordova.exec (null, null, "SQLitePlugin," open ", [{" name ":" dbname "," callback ":" cb1 "}]);
```

We have tried to fix the error. But had no success. Does anyone have an answer what we should do?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started today porting PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS to the latest Cordova API: https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS

It does not support batch execution (transactions) yet, only db.executeSQL requests.

Comment: Done implementing and tested ok on very simple case. Please confirm if it works for you, fill [issues](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS/issues) if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. We have not found any errors yet. The app is running fantastic with Corodova 2.7. We keep you informed if there are bugs.